# What regular expression would allow me to remove numbers up until english characters start? (python)

Tags: python, string

I need to turn strings into a certain format:

`#1 - New York` to `New York`

`#4 - London` to `London`

etc.

I did originally just remove special characters, however this included spaces and therefore I had errors such as `NewYork`.

My orignal way:

`''.join(filter(str.isalpha, myString))`

So I basically need to remove the #, number, spaces (before the city name starts) and the -

Comment: Remove all non-letters at the start of the string, `re.sub(r'^[\W\d_]+', '', myString)`. Or, split with `' - '` into two chunks and get the 2nd part, `myString.split(' - ',1)[-1]`

Comment: Ah right, of course. The second `.split` is so much simpler. thank you. if you submit it as an answer i'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest splitting the string into two chunks with `' - '` substring, and grab the last chunk:

```py
result = myString.split(' - ', 1)[-1]
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aQhPGr):

```py
texts = ['#1 - New York', '#4 - London']
for myString in texts:
    print( myString, '=>', myString.split(' - ', 1)[-1] )
```

Output:

```
#1 - New York => New York
#4 - London => London
```

Regarding the regex solution, you might want to remove any non-letters at the start of the string with `re.sub(r'^[\W\d_]+', '', myString)` or `re.sub(r'^[^a-zA-Z]+', '', myString)`. Note `[\W\d_]+` is a fully Unicode aware pattern while `^[^a-zA-Z]+` is ASCII only.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use regex despite having the simpler approach with split:

```regex
#\d+\s*-\s*(.*)
```

- `#` matches the # symbol
- `\d+` matches at least one digit after +
- `\s*` matches any whitespace that could follow
- `-` matches the hyphen
- `\s*` matches any whitespace that could follow
- `(.*)` creates a capture group for all the other characters up until a line break

Then to match:

```py
import re
match = re.search(r"#\d+\s*-\s*(.*)", "#1 - New York")
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
    print(result)
```